# Magento grouped products label question

Tags: magento

[image: magento]

I have tier pricing setup for one of my products in Magento. Is there any way to change the "Buy 2 for $321.60 each" to "Buy 2-4 for $321.60 each" and "Buy 5+ for $205.52 each"? It won't always be these numbers (could be "Buy 3-4" or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display logic for tier prices is located in `app/design/frontend/watercare/default/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml`

Replace the last `else` block with:

```
<?php
 $_format = 'Buy %1$s for %2$s each';

 if($index === count($_tierPrices) - 1)
 {
      $_format = 'Buy %1$s+ for %2$s each';
 }
 else
 {
      $_next = $_tierPrices[$index + 1];
      $_qty = $_next['price_qty'] - 1;
      if($_qty > 0) $_format = 'Buy %1$s-' . $_qty . ' for %2$s each';
 }

 echo $this->__($_format, $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price']);
?>
```

This will make sure that the last tier price will always be `{num}+` and the ones before it will be
 `2 - {num - 1}`.

Answer (score 1):

a quick fix to the code above (It wasn't working correctly for me in 1.7.0.2)
$_qty would stay the same for all the tiers a fix would be.

```
<?php
 $_format = 'Buy %1$s for %2$s each';

 if($index === count($_tierPrices) - 1)
 {
      $_format = 'Buy %1$s+ for %2$s each';
 }
 else
 {
      $i  = $i + 1;
      $_next = $_tierPrices[$index + $i];
      $_qty = $_next['price_qty'] -1;

      if($_qty > 0) $_format = 'Buy %1$s-' . $_qty . ' for %2$s each';
 }

 echo $this->__($_format, $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price']);
?>
```