# magento tier pricing buy x - x

Tags: php, magento, loops, count, indexing

I have tier pricing setup for a bunch of magento products and would like to change how they are shown. Currently it just says 'Buy 1 for x amount' which doesnt really explain the range properly. Is there anyway to have it say something along the lines of 'Buy 1 - 9 for x amount each'. I'm looking to have around 5 tiers per product so for example.

```
Buy 10-19 for £3.32 each
Buy 20-49 for £2.99 each
Buy 50-99 for £2.39 each
Buy 100-199 for £2.39 each
Buy 200-299 for £2.39 each
```

Note these numbers will differ across products.

I found an answered question which explains how to do this for the first tier brilliantly but i need this to work on all my tiers. Perhaps inside a loop ?

[Magento grouped products label question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352978/magento-grouped-products-label-question?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
<?php
 $_format = 'Buy %1$s for %2$s each';

 if($index === count($_tierPrices) - 1)
 {
      $_format = 'Buy %1$s+ for %2$s each';
 }
 else
 {
      $_next = $_tierPrices[$index + 1];
      $_qty = $_next['price_qty'] - 1;
      if($_qty > 0) $_format = 'Buy %1$s-' . $_qty . ' for %2$s each';
 }

 echo $this->__($_format, $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price']);
?>
```

How would you loop this code so it affects all tiers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix to do that

```
<?php
 $_format = 'Buy %1$s for %2$s each';

 if($index === count($_tierPrices) - 1)
 {
      $_format = 'Buy %1$s+ for %2$s each';
 }
 else
 {
      $i  = $i + 1;
      $_next = $_tierPrices[$index + $i];
      $_qty = $_next['price_qty'] -1;

      if($_qty > 0) $_format = 'Buy %1$s-' . $_qty . ' for %2$s each';
 }

 echo $this->__($_format, $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price']);
?>
```